# Why can't I get rid of libstdc++?

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, xcode10

Since upgrading to xcode 10 beta 6 I'm getting the error

> ld: library not found for -lstdc++
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I know that `libstdc++` has been removed from the iOS simulator but the project and all the targets have `C++ Standard Library` set to `libc++`, not `libstdc++`.

The project has nothing set in `Other Linker Flags`.  The summary of the `Other Links Flags` for the target includes `-stdlib=libstdc++`

[image: Summary of Other Linker Flags for target]

but when I double-click on it to edit it, it isn't in the list.

[image: Expanded Other Links Flags for target]

What is it that's sneaking libstdc++ in?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem was that one of my dependencies was using `libstdc++`, so Cocoapods was adding the `-stdlib=libstdc++` to the linker flags for the project.

The solution was to update the dependency to a newer version that had been built against `libc++`.

If anyone else has trouble identifying which dependency is using `libstdc++` then I recommend removing `$(inherited)` from your target's linker flags.  That will cause the linker to report missing symbols from the place that's using it, giving away which library has the problem.